# Killing a process id stored in text file in Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to write a shell script which will get the pid from a text file and kill it.

```
PID=`cat pid.txt`
echo $PID | xargs -9
```

I am getting the error :

kill : illegal pid : 954

But i have verified that the pid is correct.
What am i missing here

Comment: Try this `kill -9 $(<pid.txt)`

Comment: Great....that works...thank you...can you please post it as the answer ...i will mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this:

```
kill -9 $(<pid.txt)
```

BASH directive `$(<pid.txt)` will get content of file `pid.txt`.

For POSIX use this equivalent command:

```
kill -9 $(cat pid.txt)
```

Comment: Since the OP did not tag his question for _bash_, but for _shell_, could you please amend your answer by providing also a POSIX shell compatible solution?

Comment: For POSIX it would be: `kill -9 $(cat pid.txt)`